# Как проверить, не выходит ли элемент из родительского контейнера?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть подобная WrapPanel: [image: wrappanel]

У нее вертикальная ориентация, т.е элементы идут сверху вниз.
Количество элементов заранее неизвестно (все рисуется на основе данных из бд).
Так же неизвестен размер этих элементов. Для контекста: это хосты на датацентре, на которых работают vm'ки, программа это все визуализирует. Хостов, как и vm, может быть разное количество.

Проблема такая: мне нужно отрисовывать wrappanel (spb-2) вниз до тех пор, пока все хосты не будут показаны. Т.е 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 - отображаются правильно, а вот 7 - находится за границами родительского контейнера.

Сначала я пытался через подобный метод увеличивать размер панели, пока элементы не будут полностью видны:

```
private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
if (!element.IsVisible)
    return false;

Rect bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}
```

Но это не работает, всегда возвращает true, и вообще не очень адекватно себя ведет метод (не получает координаты). Сейчас я думаю, что правильнее будет сравнить координаты родительского и вложенного элемента. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: А скролла тат нет? Никто там случаем не ограничивает высоту панели по вертикали?Будет лучше, если вы xaml приложите, без него можно только гадать.

Comment: @John , в том и проблема, xaml'а тут нет, я все пишу в C#. Знаю что так лучше не делать, но проект по другому не сделать. Высота ограничивается родительским элементом wrappanel'и, border. Мне и нужно этот border увеличивать в высоту, пока если какой то элемент wrappanel'и не виден.

Comment: `но проект по другому не сделать` - почему? 99% задач решается через XAML. Неизвестно сколько будет объектов? Берете `ItemsControl`, задаете ему стиль, привязываете, готово. Так что, мне кажется вы сами себе придумали сложности.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а как сделать itemcontrol внутри itemcontrol'а? :)
У меня на основе данных 3 foreach цикла. Сначала датацентры, в них рисуются хосты, в них - сервера. То что на скрине - таких wrappanel'ей много, они тоже вложены в wrappanel.
Т.е: Grid > WrapPanel > WrapPanel > WrapPanel

Comment: `а как сделать itemcontrol внутри itemcontrol'а?` - так и делать, берете `ItemsControl`, привязываете его к коллекции, далее задаете нужный вид, в котором будет опять `ItemsControl`, привязанный к коллекции, которая внутри коллекции, ему делаете опять же нужный вид, ну и так до бесконечности. Если таких вложений много, то задайт гдет в ресурсах под каждый тип свой `DataTemplate` с нужным видом.